# Ignore first N matches and print (N+1)th match in grep

Tags: unix, grep

How can I make grep ignore first N matches in a file, then print (N+1)th match and all k lines after it and then exit.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 5):

Just pipe the result to [`tail(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail).  For example, if `N` is 10, use `tail +11` to skip the first 10 matches:

```
grep pattern file | tail +11
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants (if i understood his question correctly)

Comment: I don't want it. It would only print last match(es).

Comment: This does do that, and in some cases, faster than awk.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution in `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/ { found++ } found > N && printed <= K { print; printed++ }' file
```

More readably:

```
awk '
# Initialize to zero for clarity
BEGIN {
  found = 0
  printed = 0
}

# Check for a pattern match
/pattern/ {
  found++
  # Found one match
}

# Check if it's the right time to print
found > N && printed <= K {
  print
  printed++
  # Printed once
}' file
```

Make sure you fill in `pattern`, `N`, and `K` as needed.

The first block will keep track of each time the pattern is found. Once that passes the `N` threshold, the second block starts printing each line. The second block will stop printing once the `K` threshold is reached.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk`

```
awk 'd && k--&&k>=0; c>=3 && /pattern/{d=1;k=2} /pattern/{c++};' file
```

First `/3/{c++}`  increments `c` value everytime it matches pattern. If `c` reach the count of 3 for example , then set a flag (`d`) , and set the number of lines after it (`k=2`). `d && k--&&k>=0` means as long as `k`  value if more than `0` and less than `2`, print the lines.

Comment: Awk is a programming language like any other, you could use semantic variable names to make this clearer.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep 'PATTERN' FILENAME | tail -n +M
```

where `M` is N+1

Comment: It would help everyone, if you would please explain your answer.  What does it do ?  Why does it work ?  Even link a reference to grep commands

Comment: Looks similar to [Adam's answer](https://superuser.com/a/329226/399707)